# Why Intellij IDEA show my disk D: transparently?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, hidden-files

I can not understand why IJ show my root disk D: transparently? It is hidden or something?
[image]

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, it is not SSD. This partition on same HDD as disk C:

Comment: It's certainly not hidden, maybe intellij sees it as not been a "physical" ... it does this to our SSDs...

Comment: Interesting question, I have never noticed that. My C drive (SSD) is normal, my D drive (HDD) is transparent, too.